# How can I update object by model`s method, django

Tags: python, django

I need to write the method, that update object, passed by argument. Something, like this:

```
class ArticlesSerie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)


    def add_article(self, article):
         article.serie = self
         article.save()
```

and model Article:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    ...
    serie = models.ForeignKey(ArticlesSerie, blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

But this code cause error, when I try to use method add_article in shell:

```
a = Article.objects.get(id=4)
b = ArticlesSerie.objects.get(id=1)
b.add_article(a)

UserWarning: update is not implemented in this backend
```

What should I do?

Comment: Where do you get the error? Its unclear what you're trying to do

Comment: I test it in the `shell`

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the full model class(es)

Comment: Test *what*? What calls `add_article`? What is `self`? Where does the error come from?

Comment: Still not showing what you are doing/how you are calling it

Comment: @Pynchia edit it secondly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it shows in the official [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/), you can simply add the new article by adding it to the series set (of related articles)

```
class ArticlesSerie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    def add_article(self, article):
         self.article_set.add(article)
```

As you can see, it's probably not worth it to do it in a specific method since it's a one-liner, unless you want to perform further checking (e.g. on the article's fields)

Note: you might want to consider using `create` instead of `add`, if you do not need to instantiate the article beforehand.